# C++ boost shared_ptr as a hash_map key

Tags: c++, boost, neural-network, shared-ptr, hashmap

I'm making a neural network and wanted to use a hash_map to keep weight references for output neurons for each neuron:

```
class Neuron; //forward declaration was there (sorry I forgot to show it earlier)
typedef double WEIGHT;
typedef stdext::hash_map<boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>,WEIGHT> NeuronWeightMap;
class Neuron
{
private:
    NeuronWeightMap m_outputs;
    //...
public:

    Neuron();
    ~Neuron();
    //...
    WEIGHT GetWeight(const boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>& neuron) const
    {
        NeuronWeightMap::const_iterator itr = m_outputs.find(neuron);
        if( itr != m_outputs.end() )
        {
            return itr->second;
        }
        return 0.0f;
    }
};
```

I realize that I can't use the boost::shared_ptr as the key of a stdext::hash_map, so what would be another suggestion? Are there any work-arounds or is the only option to use a different key or maybe switch to an std::map?
Thanks!

Here is the errors:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xhash(61) : error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'const boost::shared_ptr<T>' to 'size_t'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=Neuron
1>        ]
1>        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xhash(99) : see reference to function template instantiation 'size_t stdext::hash_value<_Kty>(const _Kty &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xhash(98) : while compiling class template member function 'size_t stdext::hash_compare<_Kty,_Pr>::operator ()(const _Kty &) const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>,
1>            _Pr=std::less<boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>>
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\hash_map(80) : see reference to class template instantiation 'stdext::hash_compare<_Kty,_Pr>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>,
1>            _Pr=std::less<boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>>
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xhash(119) : see reference to class template instantiation 'stdext::_Hmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Tr,_Alloc,_Mfl>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>,
1>            _Ty=common_ns::WEIGHT,
1>            _Tr=stdext::hash_compare<boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>,std::less<boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>>>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>,common_ns::WEIGHT>>,
1>            _Mfl=false
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\hash_map(90) : see reference to class template instantiation 'stdext::_Hash<_Traits>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Traits=stdext::_Hmap_traits<boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>,common_ns::WEIGHT,stdext::hash_compare<boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>,std::less<boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>>>,std::allocator<std::pair<const boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>,common_ns::WEIGHT>>,false>
1>        ]
1>        FILE_PATH_REMOVED\neuralnet.h(21) : see reference to class template instantiation 'stdext::hash_map<_Kty,_Ty>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>,
1>            _Ty=common_ns::WEIGHT
1>        ]
1>NeuralNet.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xhash(61) : error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'const boost::shared_ptr<T>' to 'size_t'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=Neuron
1>        ]
1>        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xhash(99) : see reference to function template instantiation 'size_t stdext::hash_value<_Kty>(const _Kty &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xhash(98) : while compiling class template member function 'size_t stdext::hash_compare<_Kty,_Pr>::operator ()(const _Kty &) const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>,
1>            _Pr=std::less<boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>>
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\hash_map(80) : see reference to class template instantiation 'stdext::hash_compare<_Kty,_Pr>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>,
1>            _Pr=std::less<boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>>
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xhash(119) : see reference to class template instantiation 'stdext::_Hmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Tr,_Alloc,_Mfl>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>,
1>            _Ty=common_ns::WEIGHT,
1>            _Tr=stdext::hash_compare<boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>,std::less<boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>>>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::pair<const boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>,common_ns::WEIGHT>>,
1>            _Mfl=false
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\hash_map(90) : see reference to class template instantiation 'stdext::_Hash<_Traits>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Traits=stdext::_Hmap_traits<boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>,common_ns::WEIGHT,stdext::hash_compare<boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>,std::less<boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>>>,std::allocator<std::pair<const boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>,common_ns::WEIGHT>>,false>
1>        ]
1>        FILE_PATH_REMOVED\neuralnet.h(21) : see reference to class template instantiation 'stdext::hash_map<_Kty,_Ty>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>,
1>            _Ty=common_ns::WEIGHT
1>        ]
1>Generating Code...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably have `Neuron` declared in your .h file.

So the below could work:

```
struct hasher {
    size_t operator()(const boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>& n) { return (size_t)n.get(); }
};

typedef stdext::hash_map<boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>,WEIGHT,hasher> NeuronWeightMap;
```

The problem probably is that `boost:shared_ptr` has no default hashing function (what one would look like?), so you just need to provide one.

Comment: What about hashing the adress of the object pointed to by the shared_ptr?

Comment: Viktor, sounds like a good idea indeed! But @Nikolai N. Fetissov's answer sounds even better :)

Comment: `std::hash` available more recently and is a little better than `(size_t)` cast (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25124923/hashing-pointers-as-keys-for-unordered-map-in-c-stl)

Answer (score 8):

You could also provide a template specialization for the hash:

```
#include <functional>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

template<class T>
class std::tr1::hash<boost::shared_ptr<T>> {
public:
    size_t operator()(const boost::shared_ptr<T>& key) const {
        return (size_t)key.get();
    }
};
```

Works perfectly with unordered_set:

```
class Foo;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Foo> FooPtr;
typedef std::tr1::unordered_set<FooPtr> FooSet;
```

Comment: A year old post, but this was very helpful for tbb::concurrent_map with shared_ptr key and val types.

Answer (score 3):

A "normal" `Neuron*` should work as key for the `hash_map`:

```
typedef stdext::hash_map<Neuron*, WEIGHT> NeuronWeightMap;
```

If you want to lookup `shared_ptr`-Neurons you can use `shared_ptr`s `get()` method to access the raw pointer:

```
NeuronWeightMap weights;
boost::shared_ptr<Neuron> n;

weights.find(n.get());
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already use Boost, why not use `boost::unordered_map` for the hash table? It compiles out of the box with `shared_ptr` for the key, though you better check how to do it properly ([Boost.Unordered](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/unordered.html))

Answer (score 0):

From the code above what is the compiler error?

Have you tried forward declaring the class Neuron?

```
class Neuron; // class Neuron must be forward declared to be used

typedef double WEIGHT;
typedef stdext::hash_map<boost::shared_ptr<Neuron>,WEIGHT> NeuronWeightMap;


class Neuron
{
private:
    NeuronWeightMap m_outputs;
    //...
public:

    Neuron();
    ~Neuron();
    //...
};
```

a standard map should also be fine in this case, what is your specific reason to use hash_map?

Comment: Hi Baumes, I've separated the forward declaration from his code and added comments is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

I find by adding a hash_value() function I can use a shared_ptr as a key in a stdext::hash_map.
Below I compare using boost::unordered_map with std::hash_map

```
#include <boost/smart_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
#include <hash_map>
#include <assert.h>

struct MyItem
{
    int i;
};
typedef boost::shared_ptr<const MyItem> MyItem_csptr;

struct MyExtra
{
    double d;
};

//Boost's unordered_map already knows how to hash shared_ptr
typedef boost::unordered_map<MyItem_csptr,MyExtra> MapMyItemToExtra;


//But for stdext::hash_map, we need to write this:
template<class T>
size_t hash_value(const boost::shared_ptr<T>& aSptr)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<size_t>( aSptr.get() );
};
typedef stdext::hash_map<MyItem_csptr,MyExtra> MapMyItemToExtra2;


template<class MAP>
void TryMapMyItemToExtra_T()
{
    MAP tMap;

    MyItem_csptr tItem1(new MyItem);
    MyItem_csptr tItem2(new MyItem);
    tMap[tItem1].d=1.0;
    tMap[tItem1].d=1.1;
    tMap[tItem2].d=2.0;

    assert( tMap[tItem1].d == 1.1 );
    assert( tMap[tItem2].d == 2.0 );
}

void TryMapMyItemToExtra()
{
    TryMapMyItemToExtra_T<MapMyItemToExtra>();
    TryMapMyItemToExtra_T<MapMyItemToExtra2>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue with hash function arises for `stdext::hash_set` as well. Solution with declaring `hash_value()` is the best since you can declare it just once in main headers file.