# Are there any consequences in using a nullptr as a key for std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, pointers

Are there any side effects / problems that could arise in doing `someMap.insert(make_pair(nullptr, nullptr))`? Not including the dangers of dereferencing the null pointer.

Comment: If you use a pointer type as key of a map then `nullptr` is a valid value for this key. Problems may arise when you use the key (e.g. in iteration) for derefencing (i.e. access to contents) without checking. But that's a general issue with pointers, isn't it? In case of the unordered map, it depends on the hash function. If the hash function just uses the numerical value of the pointer - no problem. (I strongly believe that's the default for pointer hashing.) But if you use a customized version which dereferences the pointer... - see above.

Comment: FYI: [SO: Hashing pointers as Keys for unordered_map in C++ STL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25124923/7478597)

Comment: @Peter - What non-pointer types?

Comment: `nullptr` is incompatible with non-pointer types. That's it's whole purpose.

Comment: What is `someMap`? Is the key `std::nullptr_t` or something else?

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 I left it ambiguous to get creative answers from people's assumptions, but if you want to know it was originally `<Node *, Node *>` in my code.

Comment: @Momo It's important because `<std::nullptr_t, Node*>` would yield completely different answers. Please always ensure that you give the full context. You never know what the details might mean. That's why you're asking, right? :) Save us from having to chase for the details; just give them up-front. Easier for everybody.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 Got it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The validity of this is entirely dependent on what exactly `someMap` is.

Let's assume `someMap` has a key-type which is an actual pointer (that is, not a pointer-like type, but a `T*` of some kind).

Then the question becomes what the validity is of comparing two pointers if one of them is `nullptr`. Which means asking... how does the map compare its key type?

`std::map`'s key comparison is configurable. By default, it uses `std::less<Key>`.

This is important because *normal* ordering comparison of pointers using `<` or whatever only [imposes a partial ordering between pointer values](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.rel#3). Pointers within the same array can be compared, as well as pointers to subobjects within the same object (ordered by declaration, for standard-layout types). Therefore, order-comparisons between a null pointer and any pointer value other than another null pointer is not permitted.

Fortunately for you, `std::less` has a [specialization for pointers which imposes a total order to all pointer values](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/comparisons#2). by contrast defines a total order for all pointers.

However, if you have provided a different comparison type, one which is based on invoking `<` rather than `std::less`, then you cannot insert `nullptr` into such a `map`.

If the key-type is some kind of pointer-like type, one which does comparisons based on the value of the pointer, then again, it had better be using `std::less` instead of `<`, or you're in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no violations** in `someMap.insert(make_pair(nullptr, nullptr))`. But you need to pay attention when use this element to ***not dereference*** the `nullptr` or your program will have undefined behaviour (and may trigger a Segmentation Fault).

Note: Obviously the map need to have a pointer in the key and a pointer in the  value, or the expression can cause a compile error or in the worst case an Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: "... you got a Segmentation Fault."  If lucky.  If unlucky, it could appear to work.

Answer (score 1):

This is fine.

A null pointer is a valid value for a pointer to hold. You can do anything with it that you can do with any other valid pointer, (except dereference it).

Do make sure that you pointers are valid. If they are not, merely evaluating them has undefined behaviour ([implementation-defined behaviour since C++17](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.lval#3.3)). But evaluating a null pointer is fine because it's not "invalid", just undereferencable.